# Trouble Launching ImplicitTest

Tags: android, junit

i'm on the coursera android course. I'm trying to run week 3 Lab, about Intents, ImplicitTest but when the emulator is running, it crashes when it tries to open the browser app. And there's a message saying : "Browser isnt responding" and when i read de Junit Tab, under Failure Trace, it says: ChooserActivity not Found.

If anyone had the same problem, please tell me how to fix it.

Here's my Code:

```
private void startImplicitActivation() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

        // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL 
        // (HINT:  second parameter uses parse() from the Uri class)
        Uri pagina = Uri.parse(URL);
        Intent pag = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,pagina);


        // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
        // will carry out the baseIntent. Store the Intent in the 
        // chooserIntent variable below. HINT: using the Intent class' 
        // createChooser())

        Intent chooserIntent = null;
        chooserIntent= Intent.createChooser(pag,CHOOSER_TEXT);

        Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
        // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent
        startActivity(chooserIntent);

    }
```

And this part is MyBrowser Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Where is your crash error ?

Comment: When i see the code from ImplicitTest, it stops in this portion of code:// Wait for activity: 'com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity'
  assertTrue("ChooserActivity is not found!",
    solo.waitForActivity("ChooserActivity"));

Comment: But in general as I said, the emulator doesnt open the Browser app and the Junit Test stops.

Comment: I've also tried to launch de browser app, but it wont work.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else stack on this. Try using API level 18, if you are using 21/22 you will receive this error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  After I changed the emulator's to have a SD card with 200 MB the browser did work all right.

You might want to first check and make sure that the browser app is working before actually running the testcase .

Comment: My app (normal run) launch the browser, but without chooser.

Comment: This did the trick, I have no idea why. With the extra SD-card size it started showing the chooser in the center of the screen rather than at the bottom, and so the tests passed.

Answer (score 0):

I got a correct working version using the following :

```
<intent-filter>
    <!-- REMOVE VIEW -->
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a default browser, an opera Mini and a My Browser application. As we are given with the Robotium test cases the method that the lecturer provided was

```
solo.clickInList(2, 0);
```

We have to change it according to the way it is displayed since, to click the first item of the list, use clickInList(1) not clickInList(0). Second, the clicking is relative to the visible items on the screen, so clickInList(1) will click the first visible item on the list, not the first item overall.

As given in the lab sheet pdf file the professor had 2 lists, it worked with

```
solo.clickInlist(2,0);
```

but in my case it worked with,

```
solo.clickInList(1,1);
```

though it didn't actually worked but the test case ran successfully.